How to use FAISS and MongoDB together for creating and storing the index
I have created the index using FAISS and want to store it in MongoDB. Can we do that? if yes then how to achieve this?
I am trying to store the index to the MongoDB Atlas created using FAISS. And wanted to load it and query it whenever required.
